# Windows 7 VPN connection issue by proxy

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, proxy

In my office we are allowed to connect to internet by using a proxy which is forefront TMG I Guess and proxy gets us to other sites. It's a http proxy.

I bought a VPN from cactusvpn. But when I tried to setup vpn connection from windows 7 network setup, I couldn't connect to my vpn because It can't resolve my vpn's IP Adress. Probably because my office connection only allows to connect my proxy ip.

How can I make my windows to first connect to my proxy and then connect to vpn?

```
PC > Proxy > VPN > Internet
```

simple note : my proxy auth by windows username and password I Guess. You guys call it NTLM am I wrong ?

Comment: In forefront TMG need setup VPN tunel. And create rule allow VPN traffic.

Comment: I have no permission to use forefront. I am just connecting internet through a proxy thats all.

Comment: The problem is that the TMG default drops protocols SSTP, L2TP, PPTP, IKE. Talk to the owner of the TMG. Try connection through SSTP, if other protocols are not working.

Comment: http://www.ibvpn.com/billing/knowledgebase/86/Set-up-the-SSTP-VPN-connection-on-Windows-7.html